# asp.net page render trouble after upgrade iis from 7 to 10

Tags: asp.net, forms, iis-7, styles, iis-10

I have a website at IIS 7 in windows server 2008. After upgrade OS to windows 2019, IIS auto upgrade to version 10. All pages function are fine, but only get a blank line after form element. Is there any difference between IIS7 & IIS10 to cause the render trouble ? Or may I config machine.config or set any custom header to fix it ?

Comment: You probably only observed IIS 10 and Windows Server 2019, but there are tons of other changes (.NET Framework 4.7.x as well as others). So a lot of problems should be expected, and you should first dig further to see where the blank line comes from. Maybe just a CSS style issue?

Comment: Do you have the development version of the application? You can deploy it again to check result. Or you can migratie the application to another IIS to check result.